# DirectX RenderContext RAM/VRAM

Tags: memory, directx, ram, vram

I have 8GB or Vram (Gpu) & 16GB of Normal Ram  when allocating (creating) many lets say large 4096x4096 textures i eventual run out of Vram.. however from what i can see it then create it on ram instead.. When ever you need to render (with or to) it .. it seams to transfer the render-context from the ram to vram in order to do so. Running normal accessing many render-context over and over every frame (60fps etc) the pc lags out as it tries to transfer very high amounts back and forth. However so long the amount of new (not recently used render-contexts (etc still on ram not vram)) is references each second.. there should not be a issue (performance wise). The question is if this information is correct?

Answer (score 1):

DirectX will allocate `DEFAULT` pool resources from video RAM and/or the PCIe aperture RAM which can both be accessed by the GPU directly. Often render targets must be in video RAM, and generally video RAM is faster memory--although it greatly depends on the exact architecture of the graphics card.

What you are describing is the 'over-commit' scenario where you have allocated more resources than actually fit in the GPU-accessible resources. In this case, DirectX 11 makes a 'best-effort' which generally involves changing virtual memory mapping to get the scene to render, but the performance is obviously quite poor compared to the more normal situation.

DirectX 12 leaves dealing with 'over-commit' up to the application, much like everything else about DirectX 12 where generally "runtime magic behavior" has been removed. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d12/residency) for details on this behavior, as well as [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/TechniqueDemos/D3D12MemoryManagement)